# Converting .3mf to .blend

Tags: file-format, 3d-printing

My friend sent me a .3mf file to modify for him to 3d print. Is there a way i can convert it to a file type, that I can use in blender?

Comment: Microsoft 3D Builder (included in Windows 10) can export to obj, stl, ply

Comment: Is this preserving or converting olor data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing (April 2017), it appears that this might need to make use of an external platform like Spin 3d from [NCH Software](http://www.nchsoftware.com/3dconverter/); there does not presently seem to be a way to do it directly. However, that said, the 3MF format specification is open source, and I would expect that there will be, sooner or later, the possibility of direct import to, and direct export from, Blender.

Implementing either of these will take programming capabilities that are outside of my skillset, so I won't have direct involvement.

Comment: Do you know any online conversion tools?

Comment: @OneStig http://swiftconverter.com/convert_3d Also, lemon suggested using Microsoft's 3D Builder if you have Windows (or a VM of it)